# Querying multiple tables in SQL using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Here's my database, which is meant to contain data on musicians. My database design skills aren't the greatest but hopefully it's alright.

[image: ERM]

Tags = genres, for example rock.

Skills = guitar or vocalist

User_tags and user_skills are just being used to link the tables together, since a user can have many skills and many tags.

What I'm trying to do is query the database so that I can find users who have certain skills and are interested in certain genres. For example, find all users who are interested in rock and can play guitar. I looked up joins and managed to come up with the following query:

```
SELECT users.username, skills.skill_name
FROM user_skills
    JOIN users
        ON users.user_ID = user_skills.user_ID
    JOIN skills
        ON skills.skill_ID = user_skills.skill_ID
WHERE skills.skill_name = 'Guitar';
```

This worked, and I was able to find all users who played the guitar, but I can't figure out how to include the other half of the database as well (the tags). I tried this:

```
SELECT users.username, skills.skill_name, tags.tag_name
FROM user_skills, user_tags
    JOIN users
        ON users.user_ID = user_skills.user_ID
    JOIN skills
        ON skills.skill_ID = user_skills.skill_ID
    JOIN tags
        ON tags.tag_ID = user_tags.tag_ID
WHERE skills.skill_name = 'Guitar' AND tags.tag_name = 'Rock';
```

But I got an error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'user_skills.user_ID' in 'on clause'`

The column is definitely there though so the only thing I can think of that's breaking it is you cant join when you're selecting things from two tables. Every other example I looked at was just selecting data from one table.

Does anyone know how I can query all of my tables?

Comment: Do not mix old and new style join syntax.  A simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know I had mixed old and new styles. That's just what I managed to piece together from watching videos and doing some reading. I'll make sure I look up the correct syntax and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still select data from both tables. Give this a shot:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    users.username
 FROM
    users
 INNER JOIN
    user_skills ON users.user_id = user_skills.user_id 
 INNER JOIN
    skills ON (user_skills.skill_id = skills.skill_id AND skills.skill_name = 'Guitar')
 INNER JOIN
    user_tags ON users.user_id = user_tags.user_id
 INNER JOIN 
    tags ON (user_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id AND tags.tag_name = 'Rock')
```